# Denoting a set's cardinality of 1 by using unique existential quantification

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to first stipulate that a set has exactly one element to then further work with this exact element, and I thought it may be possible to use unique existential quantification for this, for example as follows:

$$
(\exists ! a \in S) \land a \not \in T
$$

The intended meaning is that I *first* check if there is only one element in S and, if this is true, go on to check the second condition. However, I am not sure if this is possible, because in all unique existential quantification examples that I have seen, there is always a condition directly tied to the unique existential quantifier.

Note that I am aware that I can denote the statement above as follows:

$$
|S| = 1 \land \forall a \in S, a \not \in T
$$

Is there a more elegant way to denote this?

Comment: You need to write $\exists !a\ (a \in S) \land a \not \in T)$, as is, the scope of the quantifier does not extend to the second $a$.

Comment: I need to clarify: the uniqueness should be required for $a \in S$ and in addition (given the uniqueness of $a \in S$) $a \not \in T$ must be fulfilled.

Comment: Then $\exists !a\ (a \in S) \land \forall x (x\in S\to x \not \in T)$

Comment: You could write $|S|=1\  \wedge \ S\nsubseteq T$.